# log4j.properties system variable not loading correctly

Tags: java, apache, jboss, log4j

I am using log4j 1.2.17 and deploying my application using Jboss EAP 6.2 GA. My log4j is configured using a log4j.properties file that I configured. I wanted output of a DailyRollingFileAppender to go to a directory based on a system variable. So I have it set up like this:

```
log4j.appender.MAIN.File=${EAP_HOME}/standalone/log/system.log
```

In the VM Arguments of the server configuration I have:

```
-DEAP_HOME=${EAP_HOME}
```

Where `EAP_HOME` is an Environment Variable I set up.

My Problem is that whenever I try and log, my output goes to `EAP_HOME/bin/standalone/log/system.log`

I am not sure why it is going to the **bin** directory when that is not specified anywhere in my settings.

I want it to be in `EAP_HOME/standalone/log/system.log`

Comment: Welcome to SO, we're not a forum, we're a Q&A site. Instead of writing the solution into the question, create an answer that you will eventually be able to accept. Adding answer into the question is not welcome.

Comment: I tried and it would not let because my ranking was not high enough until 8 hours after I posted.

Comment: Eventually you will be able to, which is the way this site work. Once the time is elapsed, accept your answer, don't write solved in the tittle. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was with how JBoss was grabbing the environment variable in the VM arguments. For some reason it treated $EAP_HOME like a literal string instead of an environment variable. So for now the temporary fix is replacing the $EAP_HOME in the VM argurments of the application server to the string literal path.